# Using multiprocessing and multithreading together to stream data in python

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, subprocess

I'm trying to stream btc kline data from a web api, and then doing data calculation for every interval of data stream, which is around 2 seconds. The data calculation takes longer than 2 seconds, so I need to implement multiprocessing to spawn workers for the calculation. I'm new to programing and this is way above my programing knowledge, so any help would be appreciated.

currently the code looks something like this:

```
import websocket
import json
import pandas as pd
import threading
import multiprocessing
import ccxt
import time
import os

class BinanceKlineStream():  # kline subscription
    def __init__(self, binance):
        self.kline_sub = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m'
        self.binance = binance

    def thread_stream(self):
        worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.stream)
        worker_thread.start()

    def stream(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.kline_sub, on_message=self.on_message, on_error=self.on_error)
        self.ws.run_forever(ping_interval=60)

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        json_message = json.loads(message)
        self.kline_current = pd.DataFrame([[json_message['E'], json_message['k']['o'], json_message['k']['h'], json_message['k']['l'], json_message['k']['c'], json_message['k']['v'], json_message['k']['x'], json_message['k']['t'], json_message['k']['T']]], columns=['id', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'kline_closed', 'start_time', 'close_time'])
        print('process1: ', os.getpid())

        # spawn a new process when on_message is called
        worker_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=type(self).get_kline_combined)
        worker_process.start()
        worker_process.join()

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print(error)

    @staticmethod
    def get_kline_combined():
        print('process2: ', os.getpid())
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # start streaming kline information
    binance_spot = ccxt.binance()
    stream = BinanceKlineStream(binance_spot)
    stream.thread_stream()
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ted Teng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\Ted Teng\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'BinanceKlineStream.get_kline_combined' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code? How is it *very wrong*? Spawning processes from within threads when the start method is `spawn` (default on Windows, macOS) should not raise any issues.

Comment: im getting a OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid, when the code is ran, so i assumed that im not suppose to spawn processes within a thread?

Comment: That does not have much to do with the principle of starting processes from within threads, but rather what data the processes must duplicate to start. Over here, the target function you are starting inside the process is an instance method, and hence all instance attributes need to be pickled, sent to the new process and then recreated as a new instance of the same datatype to duplicate the parent process's state. This is problematic for you because one of the instance attributes is a websocket, and these cannot be pickled.

Comment: Therefore, you need to either not store the websocket as an instance attribute, or convert `get_kline_combined` into a staticmethod (or define it outside the class).

Comment: thanks for the lenghty explaination, im less confused now, i think. gonna try the staticmethod and see how that goes.

Comment: still producing the same error unfortunately..

Comment: Post the full error and what changes you made in the sample code

Comment: Your main process starts a single child process and immediately blocks until the child process completes. This is *not* multiprocessing. Your comment suggests that you are starting multiple processes, but you do not show this.. You could possibly be shown a better way of doing what you want  but only if you posted actual code.  What you have posted is over-simplified. Also, if you have updated your code to use a static method, edit your question to show the latest code you are using along with the stack trace.

Comment: clarification: I wanted to create a single process each time 'on_message' is called, which recieves an updated on current kline usually with an interval of 1-2 seconds. The process then calculates to produce a bunch of technical indicators which takes around 5 seconds. Thus needing multiple processes doing calculations in parallel so I dont skip over any incoming kline data. NOT trying to spawn serveral processes to work on the same data.

Comment: deleted most of the calculation stuff because its long and boring and probably pretty garbage, too many iterates which is why it takes so long

Comment: @TedTeng Seems like you created another problem trying to fix your previous problem. Either define `get_kline_combined` outside the `if __name__ ...` block (and delete that `staticmethod(get_kline_combined)` line), or just revert back to your original code, where `get_kline_combined` is still a method defined inside the class. Then convert it to a `staticmethod` by adding a `@staticmethod` decorator on top of the signature of the method and pass it as a target function to `Process` class using `Processs(type(self).get_kline_combined, ...)`

Comment: @Charchit now im getting a different error.. i saw that you didnt put target= as in Process(target=type(self).get_kline_combined), when i did that i got an "AssertionError: group argument must be none for now", so i added the target=, but still getting an error, sorry for the noob questions, i kinda get the concept but not able to implement the code.

Comment: @TedTeng In case you stumble upon another related issue when discussing the question, keep in mind it's best not to overwrite your previous question details that led to the discussion. So revert back your edits to preserve the original question and then you should **add** the other code and errors that were discussed in the question (for example, give a heading as "*Update*" and include the relevant new changes in code below that heading)

Comment: ah yes, i thought the 'edited' link would show the changes in code, you're right, should make the progress obvious in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your original question, sockets are not picklable, which is why you if you are storing it as an instance attribute you cannot pass an instance method as the target function. Therefore, you should change `get_kline_combined` to a staticmethod.

Now to fix the `AttributeError`, you need to wait to join the server thread you spawned:

```
import websocket
import json
import pandas as pd
import threading
import multiprocessing
import ccxt
import time
import os

class BinanceKlineStream():  # kline subscription
    def __init__(self, binance):
        self.kline_sub = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m'
        self.binance = binance

    def thread_stream(self):
        worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.stream)
        worker_thread.start()
        # Notice
        worker_thread.join() # Notice
        # Notice

    def stream(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.kline_sub, on_message=self.on_message, on_error=self.on_error)
        self.ws.run_forever(ping_interval=60)

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        json_message = json.loads(message)
        self.kline_current = pd.DataFrame([[json_message['E'], json_message['k']['o'], json_message['k']['h'], json_message['k']['l'], json_message['k']['c'], json_message['k']['v'], json_message['k']['x'], json_message['k']['t'], json_message['k']['T']]], columns=['id', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'kline_closed', 'start_time', 'close_time'])
        print('process1: ', os.getpid())

        # spawn a new process when on_message is called
        worker_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=type(self).get_kline_combined)
        worker_process.start()
        worker_process.join()

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print(error)

    @staticmethod
    def get_kline_combined():
        print('process2: ', os.getpid())
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # start streaming kline information
    binance_spot = ccxt.binance()
    stream = BinanceKlineStream(binance_spot)
    stream.thread_stream()
```

One more thing, inside `get_kline_combined` you are altering an instance attribute:

`self.kline_current = ...`

Just keep in mind that any changes to the instance attributes are local to the process. So these won't be reflected in the main process unless you use shared memory.

**Update**

You don't need to join processes there and then, instead add them to list and then you can iterate over the list to terminate, join, whatever at your own leisure. I would also recommend you to use a Pool instead, since if there are many messages incoming you'll spawn quite a lot of processes which might not be very efficient:

```
import websocket
import json
import pandas as pd
import threading
import multiprocessing
import ccxt
import time
import os


class BinanceKlineStream():  # kline subscription
    def __init__(self, binance):
        self.kline_sub = 'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m'
        self.binance = binance
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)
        self.results = []

    def thread_stream(self):
        worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.stream)
        worker_thread.start()
        # Notice
        worker_thread.join() # Notice
        # Notice

    def stream(self):
        self.ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(self.kline_sub, on_message=self.on_message, on_error=self.on_error)
        self.ws.run_forever(ping_interval=60)

    def on_message(self, ws, message):
        json_message = json.loads(message)
        self.kline_current = pd.DataFrame([[json_message['E'], json_message['k']['o'], json_message['k']['h'], json_message['k']['l'], json_message['k']['c'], json_message['k']['v'], json_message['k']['x'], json_message['k']['t'], json_message['k']['T']]], columns=['id', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume', 'kline_closed', 'start_time', 'close_time'])
        print('process1: ', os.getpid())

        # spawn a new process when on_message is called
        worker_process = self.pool.apply_async(type(self).get_kline_combined)
        self.results.append(worker_process)

    def on_error(self, ws, error):
        print(error)

    @staticmethod
    def get_kline_combined():
        print('process2: ', os.getpid())
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # start streaming kline information
    binance_spot = ccxt.binance()
    stream = BinanceKlineStream(binance_spot)
    stream.thread_stream()
```

If you use a pool, you can get the results of the task using `self.results[index].get()`. You should also close the pool after you are done. But whichever way you want to go, you may also periodically want to iterate over `self.results` and remove tasks in their if they are done. If you don't want to do this in the main thread, then you can spawn another which continuously iterates over the list and does exactly that.

Comment: yes, thats it! thanks so much!!

Comment: one problem with this code, is that the worker_process still needs to wait for get_kline_combined to finish before another worker_process is spawned. which defeats the purpose of having additional processes to be spawned every time on_message is called. by deleting the worker_process.join() i was able to truly achieve what i intended in the beginning, but that creates a zombie process every time as well. it is possible to terminate the process within the get_kline_combined function when the code ran its length and not having the parent thread to wait for hte process to complete?

Comment: @TedTeng check edit

Comment: this works perfectly thanks!! so in this case the pool never joins but limits the number of process to be spawned? and thus to be zombified?

Comment: Processes will not be zombified, you have `self.pool` accessible to you, you can just shutdown the pool when you are done. Only reason you are creating the pool is to limit the number of processes that run concurrently, since a lot of them running together limits performance